How do I create and activate a Conda environment in a Docker container?
Is using the continuumio/miniconda3 image the only way to create a Conda environment in Docker, regardless of the type of project?
I am a beginner and still learning about Docker. Any suggestions and concepts to help me understand better would be greatly appreciated.
I know that all dependencies will be in environment.yml file but how do I put all this together?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
